# Responsive website not showing menu until page loads

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, responsive-design

I am making a website responsive with the aim to make it more "App Like" for tablet (ipad portrait and bellow) and mobile. This is(was) going well using CSS media queries.

The problem is the page loading.  The user can search for products.  But the responsive menu and other Accordian tabs are not working until the page has fully loaded.  The responsive menu is http://www.meanthemes.com/plugins/meanmenu/ and the Accordian is just Jquery.  By not working I mean the Responsive menu is not showing at all and the accordion tabs are staying open until the page has fully loaded.

I have hidden on the page other menus that are populated from the database for desktop....and have tried totally removing the code.....this did speed things up a little but still the same problem.

I know the answer would be to use something like jquery mobile(which i advised) and just start again....but the customer wanted the site to be responsive

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: maybe you can let out the heavy stuff like images and load them leter using Ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordion and other menu elements are visual components that are not initialized until the JavaScript for them is executed.

jQuery UI can be as large as 100k and depends upon jQuery which is another 80k.

Standard practise is to execute jQuery code in the `$(document).ready()` callback, but on a mobile device that can take a while to be fired. Since there is a lag time while the page is downloaded over wireless.

You have a couple of options.

- Reduce the size of jQuery UI by building the JS with only the features you require.
- Move the `<script>` include tags from the bottom of the page to the header. It's often recommended to place the scripts at the bottom, because they block downloading until completed. But if it's important that the menus appear with page you may have to move them to the header.
- You don't always have to put your JavaScript code inside a `$(document).ready()`. If you know the Javascript is placed below the DOM elements you need, then those elements are ready and can be turn into the Accordion, but jQuery must already be loaded.

Comment: going on you last recommendation, I put the call to the responsive menu below it without the $(document).ready() and that worked.  The accordians are in two places...the top and the bottom of the page with the results being in between them.  I did the same as above and put the jquery code below the top accordian and that worked....but not for the accordion at the foot.  So I un-commented the $(document).ready() which I previously used for both sets of accordions....this allowed the bottom one to work, but when I clicked the top one it opened and closed straight away...any ideas

Comment: move all your inline `<script>` tags to the bottom of the page.

Comment: by inline <script> I assume you mean       <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(".theInfo").hide(); 
  $('.menuTitle:first').addClass('active').next().show();
  $('.act:first').addClass('active').next().show();
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  $(".menuTitle").click(function()
  {
 if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
      $(this).next(".theInfo").slideToggle(600);
 }else{
  $(this).removeClass('active');
   $(this).next(".theInfo").slideToggle(600);
 }
  });
</script>...this works but the top accordion is stays open longer

Comment: yes. place that at the bottom to ensure the document elements have been loaded.

Comment: because there were two accordion menus either site lots of data being pulled from the database, putting the in line script at the bottom of the page made the top accordion stay open.  I resolved this by renaming the top accordion classes and putting the necessary inline script directly underneath....seems a bit messy...but does the trick